# Convert async Task from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous, task

I try convert this code using code C# to VB.NET converter, have some error.

```cs
private async Task OnRequestBlockResourceEventHandler(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
            => await Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    if (e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("analytics"))
                    {
                        string customBody = string.Empty;
                        e.Ok(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(customBody));
                    }
                });
```

and here are VB.NET converted code:

```vb
Private Async Function OnRequestBlockResourceEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEventArgs) As Task
    Return Await Task.Run(Function()

                              If e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("analytics") Then
                                  Dim customBody As String = String.Empty
                                  e.Ok(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(customBody))
                              End If
                          End Function)
End Function
```

and have error like this:

> Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
>
> 'Return' statements in this Async method cannot return a value since
>   the return type of the function is 'Task'. Consider changing the
>   function's return type to 'Task(Of T)'

Comment: Remove the `Return` and turn the inner `Function()` into `Sub()`.

Comment: There is generally no need for such a conversion. One of the big selling points of .NET/CLI was, that the sourcecode langauge did not mater. I honestly could not tell you wich langauge any of the Framework DLL's were written in. It does not mater. They are now CLI Libraries.

Comment: Why do you want to convert your code to VB?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the lambda function to a sub:

```
Private Async Function OnRequestBlockResourceEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEventArgs) As Task
   ' *** Change to Sub() ***
   Return Await Task.Run(Sub()

                                  If e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("analytics") Then
                                      Dim customBody As String = String.Empty
                                      e.Ok(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(customBody))
                                  End If
                              ' *** Change to End Sub ***
                            End Sub)
    End Function
```

FYI there is a free Visual Studio extension called Code Converter to/from VB.NET . "Based on Roslyn, this converter allows you to convert C# code to VB.NET and vice versa.